# Google map custom map marker image hover not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps

I just want to give an hover for google map custom map maker image. I'm using image path for styling custom image. Styles working perfectly. But hover not working.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tz4kbh39/)

**Here's my code**

```css
img[src="https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-logo-l,f_auto,dpr_auto/p/119c87f6-9b28-11e6-8026-00163ed833e7/3135981775/avatar-fortress-fight-2-logo.png"] {
   border: 4px solid #73cccc !important;
};

img[src="https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-logo-l,f_auto,dpr_auto/p/119c87f6-9b28-11e6-8026-00163ed833e7/3135981775/avatar-fortress-fight-2-logo.png"]:hover{
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="height:400px; width: 100%"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;language=en"></script>
<script>
var image = 'https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-logo-l,f_auto,dpr_auto/p/119c87f6-9b28-11e6-8026-00163ed833e7/3135981775/avatar-fortress-fight-2-logo.png';
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 13,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.423, -122.082), 
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
var myPos = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4231054, -122.08239880000002); 
var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({position: myPos, map: map, icon: image });
</script>
```

Is there any css solution or is this related with google map mouseover event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution

Add these event listeners for the marker

```
  myMarker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
    console.log("mouseover");
    this.setOpacity(0.5);
  });
    myMarker.addListener('mouseout', function() {
    console.log("mouseout");
    this.setOpacity(1);
  });
```

No need to add additonal CSS for opacity

```css
img[src="https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-logo-l,f_auto,dpr_auto/p/119c87f6-9b28-11e6-8026-00163ed833e7/3135981775/avatar-fortress-fight-2-logo.png"] {
  border: 4px solid #73cccc !important;
}

img[src="https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-logo-l,f_auto,dpr_auto/p/119c87f6-9b28-11e6-8026-00163ed833e7/3135981775/avatar-fortress-fight-2-logo.png"]:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="height:400px; width: 100%"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;language=en"></script>
<script>
  var image = 'https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-logo-l,f_auto,dpr_auto/p/119c87f6-9b28-11e6-8026-00163ed833e7/3135981775/avatar-fortress-fight-2-logo.png';
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.423, -122.082),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
  var myPos = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4231054, -122.08239880000002);
  var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myPos,
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });
  myMarker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
    console.log("mouseover");
    this.setOpacity(0.5);
  });
    myMarker.addListener('mouseout', function() {
    console.log("mouseout");
    this.setOpacity(1);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This is what I want. Thanks for your help